# Web API Login method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web Api project and i am creating a Log in operation . the code of login method  in the api controller is :

```
   [HttpGet]
            public User Login(LoginModel log)

            {   
                User myUser = db.Users
                    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.login == log.login
                                 && u.pwd == log.pwd);

                if (myUser != null)    //User was found
                {
                    return myUser;
                }
                else    //User was not found
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

                } 
            }
```

so i give the login methode a LoginModel entity  whitch is :

```
  public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
    public string pwd { get; set; }
}
```

however it didn't work and i don't even get an error when testing it with fidller given these parameter :

```
{ "login" : "rad1" , "pwd" : "13206555"}
```

and when i change it to `HttpPost` i get this result `{"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem, but you should be using POST instead of GET.

Comment: Did you change the attribute on your action method from `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: yeah when i change it i get this result `{"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhapse you should change this line:

```
public User Login(LoginModel log)
```

to

```
public string Login(LoginModel log)
```

**EDIT** - To clarify

```
[HttpGet]
public string Login(LoginModel log)
{   
    User myUser = db.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.login == log.login
            && u.pwd == log.pwd);

    if (myUser != null)    //User was found
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myUser);
    }
    else    //User was not found
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    } 
}
```

Comment: In the MVC controller i have no problems doing the Login i just made it however i need to expose data to a mobile terminal through web api with Json result

Comment: Ah I see why you were throwing an exception now. I updated my answer to reflect what you're wanting to do.